# Pan image jQuery plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

I'm searching a jQuery plugin (or some hints on how to made one) that can make me pan an image **on mouseover** just like this sample (click on "view large image" [here](http://www.topshop.com/webapp/wcs/stores/servlet/ProductDisplay?beginIndex=0&viewAllFlag=&catalogId=33057&storeId=12556&categoryId=226028&parent_categoryId=226021&productId=2077298&langId=-1)). I made something working, but it's only an animation that doesn't stop when I stop moving the mouse...

P.s.
I only need an up/down panning.

Comment: If you've made an animation, all you need to do is to stop the animation and reset it on the `mouseout' event.

Answer (score 1):

This would probably work for you:

http://flesler.blogspot.com/2007/10/jqueryscrollto.html